# make the scene look like an old television

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

How do you change what the camera sees in blender cycles. For example how do you make the camera make the scene look fuzzy like an old television. Here is an example image for fuzzy old television camera effect:
 [image]

Comment: This question [has been answered](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect).

Comment: read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/transparent-lines-for-a-hologram-like-effect and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21391/how-to-make-a-texture-always-upright-relative-to-the-global-z and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/repeat-a-generated-texture-in-cycles

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do this with the blender camera itself, so when you look through the camera just the screen of the camera does that? Would I have to like make a holographic plane on the camera make it be parented by the camera so whenever i move the camera the holographic plane follows directly on the screen of the camera?