# Rendering a pixelated image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, pixel-art

How do you make the camera in blender cycles render everything so it looks like pixels? I want everything in my scene to look pixelly like this image I found: 
[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/how-can-i-keep-low-resolution-textures-pixelated

Comment: I just noticed you also asked [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39815/599). If you are looking to get a certain effect that the linked question doesn't answer, is it possible you could edit your question to describe how the effect you want is different?

Comment: I just edited the question to show what I meant :) This effect is different from the TV like hologram effect because I want it to look like pixels as shown in the image I put for this particular question.

Comment: @gandalf3 I don't see how the linked question is a duplicate...

Comment: @cegaton From the original version of the post I got the (wrong) impression that the OP wanted to simulate a low resolution display

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution in compositing based [on this BlenderArtists thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?356225-Pixelate-Node-Tree&p=2774621#post2774621).

To pixelate a render layer or image, you simply need to use the distort *scale node* to scale it down, use the *pixelate* filter node, then *scale* it back up.

The amount of scaling up and down control the amount of pixelation.

[image: Pixelate example node tree]

EDITED: If you really want to reproduce the effect from the original image, with the pixelated outline as well, you need a slightly more complicated node setup:

[image: Node setup]

[Download blend file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/554/).

Original vs. pixelated+outline side by side:
[image: Side by side]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to add images to the image node in the render layers?

Comment: You can use your ordinary render layers node instead of the image node, I used this just as an example

Comment: Perfect just what I was looking for!

Comment: It is usually better to render to an image first though. When you render straight to render layers, when you close Blender, when you reopen it, you'll have to rerender to be able to work on it. When you use a saved image instead, it stays there, and you can continue what you started without rerendering. It's almost always best to separate your 3D work from your 2D instead of trying to do them at once.