# How do I pixelate a texture in Blender 2.91.0?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image, pixel-art

I have a perfectly clear normal image I'm using as an image texture, now I want to make it pixelated via blender. How do I do that?

Some stuff I've learned: Can't use the pixelate node because I'm using the compositing nodes, Can't find the resolution node which seems to be used in the only other answer about this question on this site, also that answer isn't updated to 2.91 so my nodes look different than the ones in that answer and I'm confused.

The answer I mentioned is linked here: [How to pixelate a texture in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles)

Comment: There is no "resolution" node. It is just a value node, that has been renamed. And note that there are two answers on that page.

Comment: Pleaese [edit] your question and clarify.  Are you asking about pixelating a texture used on a material, or pixelating an image in the compositor? For the compositor use the pixelate node.

Comment: I think this is your answer:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39859/rendering-a-pixelated-image/39868#39868